# Update a "checkBox" from a non-UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, ui-thread

I've recently coded a "battleship" program as a school project, and now decided to make a portable, mobile version of the program. By now, I'm also nearly done, the only problem I have left is that I want a checkBox (obviously on the UI thread) to constantly display if it's the players turn at any given moment. In the desktop version, I used to do that in a separate thread, so I don't block stuff on the main thread. The code is the following:

```
public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (ClientCurrentPlayer.currentPlayer == BattleshipMain.myPlayerNumber) {
                BattleshipMain.yourTurn.setChecked(true);
            } else if (ClientCurrentPlayer.currentPlayer != BattleshipMain.myPlayerNumber) {
                BattleshipMain.yourTurn.setChecked(false);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

However, this returns an Exception, stating that I cannot update view from other Threads than the one that created the view. After a bit of research, it seems like I could solve this with `runOnUiThread`. I really don't get how I'm supposed to do that, though - if I run this code on the UI thread, it would block all input, right? And I can't run the code on a separate Thread and perform the `setChecked` part in a method in the UI thread, since then it either runs the method on the wrong thread, or I can't call the method since `runOnUiThread`cannot be used in a static context. I don't get it, please help me ._.
Thanks in advance, though! :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than do a polling check like this, consider using an event driven mechanism.  Your threads can simple wait on events to come in.  The UI thread is already doing this with a `Looper` which is bound to it behind the scenes and you can leverage that by creating a `Handler` on the main thread, attaching your own `Handler.Callback` to that `Handler` and sending it messages.  Or, you can send a `Runnable` instance to the `Handler`.

Polled threads like this look very appealing, but you run into problems like what you are seeing and they can lead to poor battery performance.